# In the State of NY, if I have no income, but I have a house — do I need to pay property tax?

Tags: united-states, tax-law, real-estate, property, new-york-state

If I need to pay property tax on the house, are there any exemptions, based on the fact that I have no income?

Is it relevant what the tax assessment of the house is?

When I look at houses in house search websites, I often see in the tax history something like:
Property tax for 2017: $2,000

While for all the other years from 2000 to 2019, there is no info.

What does it mean?

Comment: I know that there is an exemption, or partial exemption, based on the age of the owner (I think it apples at age 75 or over, but I am not certain). I believe there is also a partial exemption for military veterans. The lack of info might be due to one of these. Or to a simple error in the records.

Comment: It's possible, but I doubt this is the reason here, because I have seen this pattern in many houses (i.e. only 2017 had property tax info).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I need to pay property tax on the house, are there any exemptions,
> based on the fact that I have no income?

No.

There may be property tax exemptions for other reasons, but there is not a property tax exemption for lack of income.

The most common property tax exemptions in New York are listed [here](https://www.tax.ny.gov/pit/property/exemption/index.htm). They are:

- STAR (School Tax Relief)
- Senior citizens exemption
- Veterans exemption
- Exemption for persons with disabilities
- Exemptions for agricultural properties

The stunningly long full list of property tax exemptions can be found [here](https://www.tax.ny.gov/research/property/assess/manuals/vol4/pt1/section2/sec2_01.htm). The long list mostly reflects, however, a variety of property exemptions for non-profits and governmental entities, enacted in a piecemeal fashion.

Given that you are relying upon a home search website, rather than official records, I suspect that the gaps are simply due to incomplete data for the website.

Comment: Thank you. Good to know.